# How to Unit Test a directive which binds from controller

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I have a simple directive which simply uppercases the binding from the controller.

My unit test code isn't running. Any ideas?

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">

    <div uppercase>{{main.message}}</div>

</div>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function(){
    this.message = 'hello world'
})
```

directive:

```
app.directive('uppercase', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
        link: function(scope, el, attr) {
            $timeout(function(){
                el.text(el.text().toUpperCase());
            });
        }
    }
});
```

My Unit Test currently is:

```
describe("App", function() {

    var $compile
    ,   $rootScope
    ,   $controller
    ,   MainCtrl
    ,   element;

  beforeEach(module('app'))

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_){

    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $controller = _$controller_;

    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl');



  }))

  describe("MainCtrl", function() {
    it("should have a message property", function() {
      expect(MainCtrl.message).toBe('hello world');
    });
  });

  describe("Uppercase directive", function() {
    it("should return uppercase text", function() {      

      element = '<p superman>{{MainCtrl.message}}</p>';

      element = $compile(element)($rootScope);

      $rootScope.$digest();

      expect(element.text()).toBe('HELLO WORLD');
    });
  });


});
```

I cannot use $timeout in my test, so how should I test it?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I believe that before the `expect(element.text()).toBe('HELLO WORLD');`, you'll have to flush your timeout.

I mean, you'd have an extra var called $timeout (in the beforeEach) and then, before the expected mentioned above, you'd call $timeout.flush().